# How to determine that the input is not empty without forcing user to change the input

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

So if someone needs to disable a submit button unless the user input is filled, he needs to do this:

```
        $(function () {
            $('#login').attr('disabled', true);
            $('#userinput').change(function () {
                if ($('#userinput').val() != '') {
                    $('#login').attr('disabled', false);
                } else {
                    $('#login').attr('disabled', true);
                }
            });
        });
```

And this is the html:

```
<input type="text" name="userinput" class="form-control" id="userinput">

<button id="login" class="button" disabled="disabled">Submit</button>
```

And this will work fine but the only problem exists, is that, the user MUST leave the input field in order to run the `change` event of Javascript.

However I need to run this when user is still active on the input.

So how to do that in Javascript?

Comment: use `required` attribute : `<input type="text" name="userinput" class="form-control" required >` ( and there is no needs to use `id` for all form's elements...)

Answer (score 0):

use the onfocus eventlistener:

```
$('#userinput').focus(func);
```

Comment: I tried `document.getElementById("userinput").addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {` but didn't work

Comment: Can you write the full code please

Comment: Why should he use this? Please avoid 'code-only' or short non-descriptive answers as they do not provide a clear understanding of why this fixes the problem. Perhaps read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) by SO.

Answer (score 0):

To track changes before the user leaves the input use the keyup event instead of the change even.

```
$('#userinput').on('keyup', function () {
    if ($('#userinput').val() != '') {
        $('#login').attr('disabled', false);
    } else {
        $('#login').attr('disabled', true);
    }
});
```